# Disable screen rotation in Default android Phone App

Tags: android-screen

I am working on default android Phone application.when I dial to some number or when I make a call in tablet mode,then the screen is rotating vertically.So I want to remove that vertical screen rotation.Can anyone knows please help me..
Thanks in advance..please answer to this question..

Comment: please anyone knows help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.In manifest.xml of Phone app I changed the orientation to landscape.earlier it was portrait.

```
<activity android:name="InCallScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.InCallScreen"
        android:label="@string/phoneIconLabel"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|uiMode"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
```